# How to mimic Gmail inbox "click" behavior in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

So, to be clear on what I want, how can I make an entire row behave like a MUI `<Link />` and render another component on click, while also preserving the action buttons at the end of it? My table has an edit and a delete button at each row, so the "clickable row" behavior must not override those buttons' actions.

Each row should be able to access a property called `movieId` from the fetched data, and then navigate to `/details/${movieId}`. I believe that it should be done where the table is rendered, probably where `row.getRowProps()` is called, but my knowledge on react-table is very limited yet, so I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

**CustomTable.jsx**

```
function CustomTable({ columns, data }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const tableInstance = useTable({ columns, data }, useSortBy);

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    tableInstance;

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th
                {...column.getHeaderProps([
                  column.getSortByToggleProps(),
                  { className: column.className },
                ])}
                style={{
                  color: "#fff",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  fontSize: "14px",
                  padding: "0 10px 10px 10px",
                }}
              >
                {column.render("Header")}
                <span>
                  {column.isSorted ? (
                    column.isSortedDesc ? (
                      <ArrowDownwardIcon sx={{ ml: 1 }} fontSize="inherit" />
                    ) : (
                      <ArrowUpwardIcon sx={{ ml: 1 }} fontSize="inherit" />
                    )
                  ) : (
                    ""
                  )}
                </span>
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return (
                  <td
                    {...cell.getCellProps([
                      { className: cell.column.className },
                    ])}
                    style={{
                      fontSize: "13px",
                      padding: "0 10px 0 10px",
                    }}
                  >
                    {cell.render("Cell")}
                  </td>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default CustomTable;
```

Comment: Do you have some codes or some examples you can post with your question? That will help us to address your specific issues.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot that! The code I believe is relevant is now included.